# What does the letter in VSCO preset name mean?

Tags: software, presets

I an talking about Camer RA VSCO presets. For a given file there are several version:

```
C - Agfa Scala 200
F - Agfa Scala 200
L - Agfa Scala 200
N - Agfa Scala 200
O - Agfa Scala 200
S - Agfa Scala 200
SO - Agfa Scala 200
```

Applying one or the other doesn't seems to make a difference. What does those letters stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [website help](https://support.vsco.co/hc/en-us/articles/203252594-VSCO-Film-Installing-Components) [image: screen] it looks like these match my first guess: names of camera makers.

```
C = Canon
F = Fujifilm
L = Leica
N = Nikon
O = Olympus
S = Sony
```

... and are you sure that last `SO` isn't `SC` for "Standard Cameras"?

Answer (score -1):

VSCO --- Visual Supply Company

Comment: He's not asking what VSCO stands for, but rather what the various preset codes mean